# совместить grid и list через css

Tags: css, reactjs

Пытаюсь сделать верстку подобного характера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывод контента через `react-jsx`

```
{key % 4 == 0 ? (
  <div className="grid">grid</div>
) : (
 <div className="list">list</div>
)}
```

получаю такой макет:

```
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
```

задача как из этого макета верстать как на скриншоте по средству `css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот жесть с переносами на следующую строку (по 8 на строке в 4 колонки).
И вновь пришлось отказаться от флексов и натворить жести на флоатах :D

```css
.grid, .list {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

.grid {
  height: 180px;
  background: silver;
}

.list {
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

.grid:nth-child(8n + 5) {
  margin: -120px 0 0 -40%;
}

.list:nth-child(even) {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

.list:nth-child(8n + 6), .list:nth-child(8n + 7), .list:nth-child(8n + 8) {
  margin: 0 0 0 -15%;
}

.list:nth-child(8n + 6) {
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.list:nth-child(8n + 7) {
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 180px;
}

.grid {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  background: silver;
}

.list {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
}

.list:nth-child(even) {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="grid">grid</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
<div class="list">list</div>
```

Comment: ♦ А можно сделать это резиновым с переносом? если не уместится во всю ширину?

Comment: Точно не с этим решением. Можно попробовать через `display: grid`, но мне кажется, там тоже не получится. Лучше всё-таки разметку менять и оборачивать 3 элемента в общий блок.

Comment: ♦ спасибо, будет сложно, не могу понять как на `react` разместит 3 блока в один по циклу.

Comment: @newProgrammer, я сделал, но мне кажется, что проще обернуть :)